# Deactivating all plugins and reactivating one by one, fixes conflicts. Why?

Tags: plugins, errors

I was experiencing some Javascript errors thrown in Google Chrome debug console, so I have deactivated all plugins and then re-enabled them one by one. No more errors!

How can it be that following the above procedure, sometimes eliminates conflicts?